# Robot Framework : NoSuchWindowException: Message: Unable to get browser

Tags: robotframework

I have the following keywords defined in my resource configuration:

```
Prepare Browser
    ${settings}=    Evaluate    sys.modules['selenium.webdriver'].DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER    sys,selenium.webdriver
    Set To Dictionary    ${settings}    ignoreProtectedModeSettings    ${True}
    Set To Dictionary    ${settings}    initialBrowserUrl    ${INITIAL_BROWSER_URL}
    Open Browser    ${URL}    ${BROWSER}
    go to  ${SAMPLE_URL}
```

Before my test cases execute, they call the keyword:

```
Prepare Browser
```

The problem arises when the go to method is executed before my test case is reached:

```
go to  ${SAMPLE_URL}
```

I get the same error as shown in the title:

```
 NoSuchWindowException: Message: Unable to get browser
```

I am using IE 11, and the following [API documentation](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html) to do my testing. ( Note, the browser actually opens with the ${URL}. It is only when the next line executes that the problem arises )

I've scavenged stack to determine all the possible issues that could cause this, and as a result, I have added the findings to my desired capabilities list. I have also scavenged this link to see what properties I could pass, but nothing pops up as a must: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities

Env details:

```
python 2.7.14
robotframework==3.0.2
robotframework-selenium2library==1.8.0
( IE Driver - http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/3.0/IEDriverServer_Win32_3.0.0.zip )
I have unchecked all "Enable Protected Mode" boxes in IE
IE 11
```

Comment: What version of selenium are you using? Also, why are you not directly going to the URL in question? `Open Browser   ${SAMPLE_URL}   ${BROWSER}`

Comment: You're saying that if you try to go to a page before you open the browser, you get an error that the browser isn't opened? Am I reading that right? I don't understand this sentence: "The problem arises when the go to method is executed before my test case is reached:". Can you please provide a [mcve] showing how `Prepare browser` is called. Also, are you getting any log messages or failures when you call `open browser`?

Comment: @Dandekar robotframework-selenium2library==1.8.0. && because at one point, I will have to use the go to method for my test case.

Comment: @BryanOakley I am saying that after my browser opens on line Open Browser    ${URL}    ${BROWSER}, the next line executes, which is go to  ${SAMPLE_URL}. This line crashes with the error above. My test case is never reached. Showing you my test case will probably not add any benefit, but I will update the question, in case it does.& That is the only output I get in my robot console window. ( i.e that error )

Comment: So, `open browser` succeeded without throwing any errors or adding anything in the log? Also, is `go to` the one from Selenium2Library, or have you defined your own `go to` keyword?

Comment: @BryanOakley inded, open browser succeded without any isssues. && the go to is the one provided by the library. ( As an expeirment, I downgraded to IE8, and everythinng works as expected. Hence, I presume that there is some bigger issues here with IE11. Maybe related to : https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/6511

Comment: It seems that your driver is out of date. Have you tried installing the latest driver? It appears that you're using version 3.0.0, but the latest is 3.6.0.

Comment: Have you also tried adding the site domain to the list of trusted sites? That has been known to work on Winows 8+ machines

Comment: @Dandekar Indeed I have, same result.

Comment: @BryanOakley hmm i was under the impression that 1.8.0 was the latest with pip. can you send me a link?

Comment: I'm not talking about selenium or the Selenium2Library. I'm talking about the actual platform-specific driver. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn800898(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: You need to show us the version of selenium with: 
   
   pip show selenium